# Trained an convoluted autoencoder. Now need help extracting the feature space

Tags: machine-learning, keras, feature-extraction, autoencoder

I built an autoencoder using my own data set of about 32k images. I did a 75/25 split for training/testing, and I was able to get results I'm happy with.

Now I want to be able to extract the feature space and map them to every image in my dataset and to new data that wasn't tested. I couldn't find a tutorial online that delved into using the encoder as a feature space. All I could find was to build the full network.

My code:

```
> input_img = Input(shape=(200, 200, 1))
# encoder part of the model (increased filter lyaer after each filter)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# decoder part of the model (went backwards from the encoder)
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
decoded = Cropping2D(cropping=((8,0), (8,0)), data_format=None)(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.summary()
```

Here's my net setup if anybody is interested:

```
Model: "model_22"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_23 (InputLayer)        (None, 200, 200, 1)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_186 (Conv2D)          (None, 200, 200, 16)      160       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_83 (MaxPooling (None, 100, 100, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_187 (Conv2D)          (None, 100, 100, 32)      4640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_84 (MaxPooling (None, 50, 50, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_188 (Conv2D)          (None, 50, 50, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_85 (MaxPooling (None, 25, 25, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_189 (Conv2D)          (None, 25, 25, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_86 (MaxPooling (None, 13, 13, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_190 (Conv2D)          (None, 13, 13, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_82 (UpSampling (None, 26, 26, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_191 (Conv2D)          (None, 26, 26, 64)        73792     
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_83 (UpSampling (None, 52, 52, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_192 (Conv2D)          (None, 52, 52, 32)        18464     
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_84 (UpSampling (None, 104, 104, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_193 (Conv2D)          (None, 104, 104, 16)      4624      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_85 (UpSampling (None, 208, 208, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_194 (Conv2D)          (None, 208, 208, 1)       145       
_________________________________________________________________
cropping2d_2 (Cropping2D)    (None, 200, 200, 1)       0         
=================================================================
Total params: 341,761
Trainable params: 341,761
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Then my training:

```
autoencoder.fit(train, train,
                epochs=3,
                batch_size=128,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(test, test))
```

My results:

```
Train on 23412 samples, validate on 7805 samples
Epoch 1/3
23412/23412 [==============================] - 773s 33ms/step - loss: 0.0620 - val_loss: 0.0398
Epoch 2/3
23412/23412 [==============================] - 715s 31ms/step - loss: 0.0349 - val_loss: 0.0349
Epoch 3/3
23412/23412 [==============================] - 753s 32ms/step - loss: 0.0314 - val_loss: 0.0319
```

Rather not share the images, but they look well reconstructed.

Thank you for all and any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand your questions, but do you want to get the resulting feature space for every image you trained on as well as others. Why not just do this?

Name your encoded layer in your autoencoder architecture as 'embedding.'  Then create the encoder the following way:

```
embedding_layer = autoencoder.get_layer(name='embedding').output
encoder = Model(input_img,embedding_layer)
```

Comment: ya, I want to get the feature space of all my images, and then new images I recieve. Then find the shortest distnace between images. With the code you've shown will my encoder be the feature space? and I can compare that encoder to others? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you that worked. I wasn't sure how I was suppose to use AutoEncoders and split them up. Thank you!